# Constructing a command from inside a loop doesn't render the '=' sign

Tags: bash

I am trying to have my script read from a `.env` file and export environment variables in the session I am calling this script from.

Here's my `.env` file:

```
# Some comment here
NODE_ENV=development
JWKS_AUDIENCE=test test02
```

and my bash script that reads from this file:

`set-local-env.sh`:

```
IFS='=' # delimiter
while read LINE
    do 
        if [[ $LINE =~ ^\#.* ]] ;
        then
            continue
        fi
        read -ra ADDR <<< "$LINE"
        export ${ADDR[0]}=\"${ADDR[1]}\"
done < .env.development

export myvar="sup"
```

I run it by using `source` to set the environment of the session running it:

```
$ source ./set-local-env.sh
-bash: export: `"development "': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `"test test02"': not a valid identifier
```

The last export at the bottom `myvar="sup"` is working:

```
$ echo $myvar
sup
```

My guess was that the command isn't being constructed properly, what I am get out of `export ${ADDR[0]}=\"${ADDR[1]}\"` is:

- `export NODE_ENV="development"`
- `export JWKS_AUDIENCE="test test02"`

I tried echoing out the `export` commands (i.e. `echo export ${ADDR[0]}=\"${ADDR[1]}\"`) and here's what I got:

```
export NODE_ENV "development"
export JWKS_AUDIENCE "test test02"
export myvar=sup
```

The two `exports` that are generated from inside the loop do not have the equal sign. Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: if I didn't have the "array" in there I would've done that but it wouldn't work with that part `export JWKS_AUDIENCE "test test02"`

Comment: Ah, I didn't even look at your code before saying that. Ditch that `read -ra ..` and just do `export "$LINE"`

Comment: @oguzismail whowa, that worked!! I didn't know what you meant by the two dots but I assumed you meant `read -ra ADDR` ?

Comment: yes that's what I meant. glad to have helped

Comment: can you add that as an answer please to help anyone else who bumps into this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this:

```
read -ra ADDR <<< "$LINE"
export ${ADDR[0]}=\"${ADDR[1]}\"
```

and this:

```
IFS='='
```

Just do as follows and you're good to go:

```
export "$LINE"
```

Comment: Ah ! There is no word-splitting issue when used that way ! The op certainly thought there would be word-splitting issues and that is why they did `export ${ADDR[0]}=\"${ADDR[1]}\"` which is the core  (issue) of the question which is left for a reader to figure out..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just source your variables normally, then export them by name alone?

```
. file.env
while IFS=\= read foo bar; do
  [[ ! "$foo" =~ ^\# ]] && export $foo
done < file.env
```

Comment: It would work without the array part `JWKS_AUDIENCE=test test02` but when I run it with that in there i get:

`bash: test02: command not found`

Comment: @NaguibIhab `JWKS_AUDIENCE`  is not an array unless you intend it to be. Please update the question if so.

Comment: @NaguibIhab, `JWKS_AUDIENCE=(test test02)`